# How to select specific csv files from a folder in python?

Tags: python, pandas, file

this is a 2 part question.
I have a folder (existing in the same directory as the python script) with a lot of csv files and I want to read only specific csv files from the folder into python in order to later merge it into one data frame.

1. I do not want to read all the csv files from the folder, just the csv files that have the substring "BANK_NIFTY_5MINs*". Can someone please help on how I can do that?

The files I want to read are named as:

BANK_NIFTY_5MINs_2020-01-01.csv,
BANK_NIFTY_5MINs_2020-01-02.csv,
BANK_NIFTY_5MINs_2020-01-03.csv and so on.

I have tried with the following code but it does not work. 'files' variable does not store anything. (The code works if the folder consists of only the files I want to work with - But that is not what I want):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = 'C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Test/2020/'
files = sorted(glob.glob(path + "/BANK_NIFTY_5MINs*.csv"),reverse=True)

#Code to merge the files
df = pd.merge(
    read_csv(files.pop()),
    read_csv(files.pop()),
    left_index=True, 
    right_index=True
)
while files:
    df = pd.merge(
        df, 
        read_csv(files.pop()), 
        left_index=True, 
        right_index=True,
        how='outer'
    )
```

2. Also, is there a way I can access the folder without specifying the absolute path of the directory? So that it runs on another system without having to change the path.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: maybe first check `os.listdir("'C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Test/2020/")` to see what you really have in folder. Maybe files have little different name. OR maybe you should use `r"C:\...\..."` instead of `"C:/.../..."`. BTW: when you add `".../" + "/..."` then you get `...//...` and this can also makes problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use relative path:

```
import os

currentDir = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
absolutePath = os.path.join(currentDir, "the/relative/path")
```

For the file name, RegEx should work fine, but maybe a simple solution like this will work better:

```
for file in os.listdir(currentDir):
    if filename.startswith("BANK_NIFTY_5MINs") and filename.endswith(".csv"):
        # do the thing that you want here
```